# Where or were, what is correct?

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

> Where the police at the scene?
>   Were the police at the scene?

Surely the correct word would be "were"?

Comment: Yes, of course since "where" and "were" are completely different words.  It depends what you want to say, can you please edit your question to add context?  Did you see this on a test or in a textbook somewhere?

Comment: @Helwil, It would be better if you could include the text or reference or context of the question that you'r asking for, which would benifit both you and answerer!

Comment: I was surprised to see the question in an accident claims form. The insurance company is asking if police attended an accident.

Comment: It's a fairly common mistake that people make, but it is definitely a mistake.  Perhaps the person who wrote it had the question "where were the police?" in their mind while they were writing it.

Comment: I hope i made the question more clear? The claims form is for car accidents. There are several questions, one being "Where the police at the scene?" To me the correct question would be "Were the police at the scene" I started questioning myself when no one at my office agreed with me.

Answer (score 1):

The first version, with "Where", is incorrect English. The closest I could get would be:

> Where were the police? At the scene?

Or, in one sentence:

> Were the police at the scene.

So if you saw it written down, it was a typo.